# Centering the drawing of a tic tac toe board game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My code draws the grid and sets the Xs and Os. My problem is that it does it all in the upper right corner of the screen. I want to find a way to do it all but centered. The issue is that I want this to be as aesthetic as possible. Everything works and I have no problem with it at all, except for the position. I can't find a command to set my board in the center of the screen.

```
from turtle import*

def tttDrawLineFromMidpoint(pen, orientation, lineLength):
    pen.setheading(orientation)
    pen.down()
    pen.fd(lineLength/2)
    pen.bk(lineLength)
    pen.fd(lineLength/2)

def tttDrawXFromMidpoint(pen, cellSize):
        lineLength = 1.41 * cellSize
        tttDrawLineFromMidpoint(pen, 45, lineLength)
        tttDrawLineFromMidpoint(pen, 135, lineLength)

def tttDrawX(pen, cellsize, row, col):

        x=col*cellsize
        y=row*cellsize

        x+=cellsize/2
        y+=cellsize/2

        pen.up()
        pen.goto(x,y)

        xSize = cellsize/2
        tttDrawXFromMidpoint(pen, xSize)

def tttDrawCircleFromPoint(pen, orientation,lineLength):
        pen.setheading(orientation)
        pen.down()
        pen.up()
        pen.fd(lineLength/1.5)
        pen.lt(45)
        pen.bk(25)
        pen.down()
        pen.circle(lineLength/2)

def tttDrawOFromPoint(pen, cellSize):
        lineLength = cellSize
        tttDrawCircleFromPoint(pen,90, lineLength)

def tttDrawO(pen, cellsize, row, col):

        x=col*cellsize
        y=row*cellsize

        x+=cellsize/2
        y+=cellsize/2

        pen.up()
        pen.goto(x,y)

        oSize = cellsize/2
        tttDrawOFromPoint(pen, oSize)

def tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen, orientation, lineLength):
        pen.setheading(orientation)
        pen.down()
        pen.fd(lineLength)
        pen.bk(lineLength)

def tttDrawGrid(pen,cellSize):
    pen.ht()

    for i in range (2):
                pen.up()
                pen.goto(0, cellSize * (i+1))
                tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen,0,3*cellSize)
    for i in range(2):
                pen.up()
                pen.goto(cellSize*(i+1),0)
                tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen,90,3*cellSize)

def ttt(cellSize):
        marker = Turtle()
        marker.width(3)
        marker.color('purple')
        tttDrawGrid(marker,cellSize)

def tttDrawXOTest(cellSize):
        marker = Turtle()
        marker.width(3)
        marker.color('purple')
        tttDrawGrid(marker,cellSize)
        xTurtle = Turtle()
        xTurtle.width(3)
        xTurtle.color('orange')
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                    tttDrawX(xTurtle, cellSize, row, col)

        xTurtle = Turtle()
        xTurtle.width(3)
        xTurtle.color('pink')
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                    tttDrawO(xTurtle, cellSize, row, col)


t=Turtle()
t.ht()
ttt(100)
print("Let's Play Tic Tac Toe >:D")
print("X goes first!")
x = input("Choose a row between 0-2: ")
x = int(x)
x = x
y = input("Choose a coluumn between 0-2: ")
y = int(y)
tttDrawX(t,100,x,y)

print("O goes next!")
x = input("Choose a row between 0-2: ")
x = int(x)
x = x
y = input("Choose a coluumn between 0-2: ")
y = int(y)
tttDrawO(t,100,x,y)

exitonclick()
```

Comment: is this for a class, for practice, or is it to actually try to make a good game? Because turtles are only useful for learning purposes

Comment: Class assignment. The homework was to create the circle and do the X and O test. I already did it all is just that it's not centered -__-
This game is compiled by several assignments. Every homework is doing another piece of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about centering the board, I've removed everything but the drawing of the board in my example code below.  The key is to do your math around the zero point, so the positions of the pairs of lines in the tic-tac-toe board only really differ from each other by their sign:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen, orientation, lineLength):
    pen.setheading(orientation)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(lineLength)

def tttDrawGrid(pen, cellSize):
    for sign in (-1, 1):
        pen.up()
        pen.goto(-3 * cellSize / 2, sign * cellSize / 2)
        tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen, 0, 3 * cellSize)

    for sign in (-1, 1):
        pen.up()
        pen.goto(sign * cellSize / 2, -3 * cellSize / 2)
        tttDrawLineFromEnd(pen, 90, 3 * cellSize)

def ttt(cellSize):
    marker = Turtle(visible=False)
    marker.width(3)
    marker.color('purple')
    tttDrawGrid(marker, cellSize)

ttt(100)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

One trick I use when programming with a turtle is right after I create the turtle, I call `turtle.dot()` to make a visible spot in the exact center of the screen so I know if I'm drawing where I expect.  I then remove this debugging aid in my final code.